# Using .ico in img tag

Tags: html, image, firefox, ico

I have faced next strange behavior in Firefox when use ico file as src in img tag.
When It opens in Firefox  (latest version), it has 16x16 format despite of the fact that ico original format is 128x128.
In other browser (Chrome, IE) everything works great.
Just open elephant-128x128.ico in Chrome and Firefox and you will see the difference.

```
<img height='128' src="http://icons.iconseeker.com/ico/cloth-dolls-icons/elephant-128x128.ico">


https://jsfiddle.net/qwx2sxzg/1/
```

or
http://icons.iconseeker.com/ico/cloth-dolls-icons/elephant-128x128.ico
Does anybody has idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

Your best bet is to convert `ico` files to another format, since it is not compatible with all browsers.

[Image Format Support For Web Browsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support)

*There is no other workaround for it.*

Comment: Thank you, we decided pass size to the server and convert ico to png.

Comment: @SergeyZubatkin you are welcome, make sure you save the converted image, so the server won't have to convert images on each request.